# Economics.SE closing; candidates for migration

Tags: discussion, migration

The Economics board is closing Friday, May 4, and they want to move as many questions to new sites as possible. These appear to be relevant for scicomp.SE:

- [Simulation in Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/simulation-in-economics)
- [Best program for producing economics graphs on Linux](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/best-program-for-producing-economics-graphs-on-linux)
- [Mathematical formalism for the economics of traffic flow](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/mathematical-formalism-for-the-economics-of-traffic-flow)
- [Economy simulation software](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/economy-simulation-software)

Answer (score 1):

Of these questions, [Best program for producing economics graphs on Linux](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/best-program-for-producing-economics-graphs-on-linux) is the best candidate for migration, in that it's the most "computational science"-like, and will probably get the most satisfactory answers (considering the perspective of the original poster) from the audience on this site.

The remaining three questions are a grab bag. If we have economists in the audience, then I think [Simulation in Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/simulation-in-economics) and [Mathematical formalism for the economics of traffic flow](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/mathematical-formalism-for-the-economics-of-traffic-flow) could get good answers or bad answers, depending on whether or not we have economists in the audience. Economics seems really integral to these questions. I think they could migrate over here just fine, because we get application-specific questions here all the time, but the success or failure of those questions really depends on someone knowing the application enough to provide insight in their answers.

[Economy simulation software](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/economy-simulation-software) isn't a good candidate for migration, in my opinion, because I look at the question and see it as unclear. It also has an accepted answer, which normally means it shouldn't get migrated, but I don't know if questions with accepted answers should get migrated if their site is going to be closed. On the other hand, the author of the accepted answer for that question seemed to know exactly what the asker was talking about, and perhaps that again has to do with economics background. If we were to migrate it, I'd ask the poster to clarify his question, but I doubt they'll get back to editing their question because it already has an accepted answer, and if it gets migrated, it will be on a different site, to boot.

Comment: Geoff: I believe that the site is going away—they've talked about making the questions and answers available for download, which means that they're not keeping the site around.

Comment: @aeismail: Good to know. I still think that the economy simulation software is a bad choice for migration for the other reasons I mentioned. I'm willing to hear counterarguments, but at the moment, I think it's a vague question for SciComp.

Comment: Fair enough. I was doing a quick scan of topics. (And that question got migrated to programmers.SE (?!?), so it's a moot point now anyways.)

Comment: @aeismail: Haha, that makes even less sense. I appreciate the work you put in; I've been so buried with thesis stuff that I've been focusing purely on site maintenance and not the broader SE picture.